# Dynamically fill path for folders after choosing version in Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I want to parse a directory say \WindowsServer\Share\ProductName\version(s) and have the user choose a version from the dropdown. Then automatically parse the directories for specific folder and post them as separate parameters dynamically for a job.

[Screen Shot Example of what I would like it to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFkSJ.png)

The problem I have encountered is that Jenkins groovy won't search a directory dynamically unless you use the "File system objects list Parameter".

Other Details:
Jenkins is running on a Windows Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Active Choices Reactive Parameter` for `SQLFolderFound` and specify `VersionNumber` as referenced parameter, then fill Groovy Script to search and return desired items in an array.

Groovy Script example

```
searchFolder = '\WindowsServer\Share\ProductName\' + VersionNumber

// code to search desired folder from above searchFolder 

targetFolder = ....

return [targetFolder]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Yong. I used what you provided above back in 2020 and improved upon the solution. I needed a way to parse the directories only and allow the user to pick first. I also need the version number to be separate from the directory structure so this works out very nicely.

Part 1: Parse the directory with an Active Choices Parameter using a Groovy script.

1. Create an "Active Choices Parameter"
2. Name "Version"
3. Choose Script
4. Enter the following Groovy script.

```
import groovy.io.*

def listfiles(dir) {
    dlist = []
    flist = []
    new File(dir).eachDir {dlist << it.name }
    dlist.sort()
    new File(dir).eachFile(FileType.FILES, {flist << it.name })
    flist.sort()
    return (dlist).flatten()
    // Not listing file list now.
    //return (dlist << flist).flatten()
}

fs = listfiles("//server/share/folder/product/release-code")
// sometimes you want version numbers reversed so it's easier to parse.
fs.reverse()
```

Part 2: Create an Active Choices Reactive Parameter that can be used as a reference.

1. Create an "Active Choices Reactive Parameter"
2. Name "SourcePath"
3. Choose Script "Groovy Script"

```
//Note: needs the double slashes
return ['\\\\server\\share\\folder\\product\\release-code\\' + Version + '\\WebCode']
```

4. Add the Name "Version" (from Part 1) to the Referenced parameters.

Now the user can choose a version from the drop-down and populate the environment variable "SourcePath" with the variable for the "Version".

I have been using this for the last two years and people have been very happy with it. I think you can do this with a Jenkinsfile if you want.